# i need send a parameter from Url mapping class in grails application(its a different use case)

Tags: grails

i have this

```
 "/"{controller = "normal"
          action = "index"
      }
```

this will come in to play when i give `localhost:8080` and my need is that i have to send a parameter through this so that requests starting `/` will enter in to that specified controller and action with that parameter so accordingly i can make some condition to put some functionality in my view. so requests from that mapping have to send some parameter which should not alter my URL which is `localhost:8080` with that parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
"/" {
    controller = "normal"
    action = "index"
    param = "value"
}
```

Or

```
"/"( controller:"normal", action:"index", param:"value" )
```

Comment: how can i access that param in my action?

Comment: @kiran `params.param` should do it?

Comment: when i print params using log, i didn't see any parameters with that name or value param.

Comment: Can we pass multiple params ? Both of your solution are not working for me using grails 2.2.2 This works but only with one param ´"/"(controller: 'userStatistic', action: 'index' ){filter = "TEST"}´

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me;

```
"/"( controller:"admin", action:"index") {
   myparam = "value"
}
```

for passing a parameter of myparam with a value of "value" through to the admin controller.

Then in my controller I can easily reference it like;

```
def index() {
   println params.myparam
}

value
```