# UrlMappings.groovy default view with parameters

Tags: grails, url-mapping

In my UrlMapping.groovy I am trying to reach a specific view of controller sending a param, but this does not work:

```
"/"(view:'/myController/myAction?myParam=value')
"/"(controller:"myController" action="myAction" params:[myParam:"value"])
"/"(controller:"myController" action="myAction" myParam:"value")
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 "/"(controller:"myController", action:"myAction"){ param="value"}
```

Comment: please eloborate if you are giving answer so that ops/others can understand it .

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted here worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28870770/695318

It even works for multiple parameters:

```
"/some/path"( controller:"admin", action:"whatever") {
   myparam = "value"
   anotherParam = "Hello World"
}
```

Access from a controller, e.g. AdminController

```
def whatever() {
   println params.myparam
   println params.anotherParam
}

value
Hello World
```